# yum having conflicts while attempting to install php-xml

Tags: centos, php, yum

Using CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core) and running PHP 5.5.38 (cli) (built: Jul 21 2016 12:25:20). Attempting to install php-xml but am receiving the following issue:

```
sudo yum install php-xml
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * epel: mirror.symnds.com
 * webtatic: us-east.repo.webtatic.com
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-xml.x86_64 0:5.4.16-36.3.el7_2 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.16-36.3.el7_2 for package: php-xml-5.4.16-36.3.el7_2.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-common.x86_64 0:5.4.16-36.3.el7_2 will be installed
--> Processing Conflict: php55w-common-5.5.38-1.w7.x86_64 conflicts php-common < 5.5
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: php55w-common conflicts with php-common-5.4.16-36.3.el7_2.x86_64
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

If I execute "yum list installed php" it shows this:

```
yum list installed php*
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * epel: mirror.symnds.com
 * webtatic: us-east.repo.webtatic.com
Installed Packages
php55w.x86_64                                                                             5.5.38-1.w7                                                                       @webtatic
php55w-cli.x86_64                                                                         5.5.38-1.w7                                                                       @webtatic
php55w-common.x86_64                                                                      5.5.38-1.w7                                                                       @webtatic
php55w-mysql.x86_64                                                                       5.5.38-1.w7                                                                       @webtatic
php55w-pdo.x86_64                                                                         5.5.38-1.w7                                                                       @webtatic
```

So I'm not seeing any installed PHP 5.4 packages. Any suggestions?

Comment: You probably need `php55w-xml`.

Comment: You installed PHP from a third party repo and therefore must get your PHP extensions from the same repo.